# terraform upgrade cloud composer from 1.0 to 2.0?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-composer, terraform-provider-gcp

I try to use terraform to upgrade composer from 1.0 to 2.0. I got the following error. Would you please help me with issue? Where does the issue come from?

Terraform has been successfully initialized!
$ terraform apply -input=false $PLAN
module.composer.google_composer_environment.composer: Creating...

```
│ Warning: Version constraints inside provider configuration blocks are deprecated
│ 
│   on provider.tf line 2, in provider "google":
│    2:     version = "~> 3.22"
│ 
│ Terraform 0.13 and earlier allowed provider version constraints inside the
│ provider configuration block, but that is now deprecated and will be
│ removed in a future version of Terraform. To silence this warning, move the
│ provider version constraint into the required_providers block.
╵
╷
│ Error: googleapi: Error 400: Found 2 problems:
│   1) Error validating property [core]store_dag_code. Overriding [core]store_dag_code is not permitted. 
│   2) Error validating property [core]store_serialized_dags. Overriding [core]store_serialized_dags is not permitted. , badRequest
│ 
│   with module.composer.google_composer_environment.composer,
│   on ../modules/composer/main.tf line 2, in resource "google_composer_environment" "composer":
│    2: resource "google_composer_environment" "composer" {
│ 
╵
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrades for Composer 1.x versions to Composer 2.x are not supported at the moment. Indeed, users need to create Composer 2.x from scratch.

One can use migration tool to migrate history of DAGs/tasks from Composer1/Airflow 1 to Composer 2/Airflow 2 - but it's a manual step: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/composer/tools/composer_db_transfer.md

Answer (score 1):

Terraform errors out because upgrade from Composer 1 to Composer 2 is not permitted by GCP Cloud Composer. See [Composer upgrade limitations](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/upgrading#limitations).

> You can only upgrade to the latest Cloud Composer version within the
> same major version, such as **composer-1.12.4-airflow-1.10.10 to
> composer-1.13.0-airflow-1.10.10**.
>
> Upgrading from
> **composer-1.4.0-airflow-1.10.0 to composer-2.0.0-airflow-1.10.0 is not**
> **permitted** because the Cloud Composer major version changes from 1 to
> 2.

The only workaround to upgrade is to create a new Cloud Composer 2.0 instance.

Comment: I am creating a new instance using. terraform backend . I am not replacing the existing instance  {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "xxxxxxxxxx"
    prefix = "data-engineering-infrastructure/xxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx"
  }
}

Comment: terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "xxxxxxxx"
    prefix = "xxxxxxx/gcp/xxxxx/dev_upgrade"
  }
}

Comment: @Dataflower I see. The title was a bit misleading since says upgrade to 2.0. It might be better to change the title and the content of the question to error in creating a 2.0 instance? You can also include your terraform code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are considering a better approach, for minors versions you can update in-place the Composer 2, as explained in the documentation here

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/composer_environment#image_version

You must use the `google-beta` provider at the time I'm writing this answer.

Major can't be updated in-place but that's understable.